# How do I distort a mesh like fabric?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I have mesh model of a shirt that I want to reshape as if it were being put on - with the surface rumpled and bunched up - but I don't want the mesh to lose its overall shape while I modify it, as if it were real fabric. Is there some way to do this?
I have tried the proportional editing tool but it is inadequate.

Comment: What you're looking for is a cloth simulation. Here's a good tutorial to get you started: http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/make-towels/

Comment: That's fine but it was not what I was looking for. I want to model someone putting on a piece of clothing, like a tee shirt. There isn't much draping - but it should wrinkle and cover the arms etc.

Comment: What would be really good for this type of task is a plugin tool  that allowed only a certain amount of stretch or bend at any vertex, with those two properties being adjustable: then you would distort the mesh as desired and have the software "correct" it according to those limits.